# Logistic regression for hierarchical / nested (3 level) data

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, multicollinearity, weighted-regression

**Research Problem**

We are trying to help universities recruit as many students as possible for different projects for a good cause. To be eligible for any project offered by their university, students can self-register online via a brief form that asks for contact information and some more data. Some questions are mandatory, others aren’t. We see that a lot of students drop out filling in the form. (BTW this is not my real research problem, but will serve as a good analogy).

So our hypothesis is:
*The number (and type) of questions influence the drop out rate above and beyond other predictors. The more (mandatory) fields, the lower the probability of a student submitting the form.*

**Data Structure**

Our research question seems quite simple, but the structure of our data has some pitfalls:

- Each row is a student that opened an application form with their respective university (e.g. city), project (e.g. project category) and individual level variables (e.g. sex, device they opened the form with)
- The two predictor variables of interest are on yet another level, the application form level (see details below). **These are the only numeric predictors, all confounding variables are categorical.**
- The outcome is whether the student submitted the application form or not (Boolean)
- The data is hierarchical:

  - We have a total of ~80 universities with a total of ~4,000 different projects and ~30,000 rows (students).
  - All distributions are skewed: Some universities have hundreds of projects, some have only two. Some projects have hundreds of student applicants, some have less than 10.
  - We know from exploratory data analysis that within each university and project, submission rates do share a high proportion of variance so we want to consider that.
- The application forms do not vary a lot between universities / projects and if they do, they are mostly the same within any university:

  - Each university can have their own application form, but many use the same default  form that contains only 4 mandatory fields
  - Most universities do use one form for all student recruitment, but some use different form types for different project categories
  - This means that also in the predictor variables, we tend to have unbalanced classes / little variance in the no. of fields

So overall, we have a lot of multicollinearity in the data if we use it row-wise.

**Question / Current Approach**

*Our question is IF AND HOW we can robustly measure the effect of the number of fields on the outcome (students submits form or not) in such a way that it does not only reflect the differences between the universities (or projects).*

We were thinking about either including university and project IDs as confounding variables into our logistic regression model, or hierarchical modelling. But is this even possible with so many different universities and projects?

Alternatively, we could aggregate the data on project level and compute dummy variables for the individual level variables, e.g. “ratio_male” = 0.27. We could then use the submission rates per project as the outcome variable for a (weighted) linear regression. But wouldn’t that make us lose lots of information? And in any case, the data would still be hierarchical (projects nested in universities)…

Thanks so much in advance for any input!

Comment: Is the goal to make more students submit the form or learn how to provide students with the necessary information to make an informed choice? I don't see why *not* submitting the form is definitely the wrong outcome for either the student or the projects.

Comment: Since there are so many participating university and programs, I think there is an opportunity to conduct experiments to compare the effectiveness of different questionnaires. (Perhaps, I'm not sure whether that's actually a possibility or the universities design the questionnaires themselves.) For example, you can pair the universities (by size, location, specialty etc) and then use a short and a long questionnaire and compare the questionnaire completion rate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments :-)

@dipetkov as I said, the story around universities is just an analogy to our use case. In the real use case, it is paramount that a high percentage of "students" submit the form and we want to advice the universities on best practices of how to achieve this goal.

As for the experiments (or maybe quasi experiments in our case as we cannot do random assignment unfortunately), yes we thought about this approach and then do propensity score matching to level out confounders :-) It's few universites that use two or more forms, but it's worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Great -- you already know that you can do matching without doing "real-world" experiments. I'm still wondering whether the analysis will end up with the "insight" that "ask no question at all -> everyone submits". I guess you'll have to do the analysis to find out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks :-) Yes, I have done that for a former analysis. The difference there was that there was a lot more variation within each university regarding the variable of interest (meaning that we had many projects with different configurations within each university). Unfortunately, that's not the case for the number of fields in the application form - out of more than 80 universities, there are only a handful that use more than one configuration. So all explained variance is kind of "absorbed in the university itself" if you know what I mean :-D But thanks a lot anyway! :-)

Comment: P.S.: Each form has a default setting of 4 mandatory fields that cannot be deleted. So we were rather hoping for an insight like "with each mandatory field you add, your submission rate goes down by XX%" ;-)